# Delete trailing hashes in a list of URLs using powershell?

Tags: powershell, regex, find-and-replace, pipe

I got a bit rusty with PowerShell, and I am missing the correct search terms, so I hoping asking here is ok.

I have list of URL of the following structure:

```
/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.en.pdf?42da4200dd38971a82c2d
/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.de.pdf?42da4200dd38971a82c2d
...
```

Using PowerShell's `{$_.replace("x","y")}` within a pipe, I want to delete the trailing hash, so that I end up with

```
/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.en.pdf
/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.de.pdf
...
```

As RegEx, the `x` would be e.g. of the form `\?[0-9a-z]*$` and `y` would be an empty string, but that does not work.

Comment: It looks like this is indeed a possibility. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potentially simple solution would be to use [`Split()`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) on the `?` character and only list the first index `[0]` rather than regex which would be the part before the `?` character.

### Simple Example

```
"/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.en.pdf?42da4200dd38971a82c2d" | % { $_.Split("?")[0] }
```

**Output**

```
/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.en.pdf
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

Comment: This, but without a foreach `("/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.en.pdf?42da4200dd38971a82c2d").Split("?")[0]`

Comment: True, since your example showed `{$_.replace("x","y")}` I assumed you were using `foreach` but if you have further case I can test, let me know so I can emulate accordingly.

Comment: If looks like the regex may be something like this from what I tested just for FYI with a simple example... `(^.*)?\?` e.g. `"/pub/pdf/ssm.supervisorymanual.en.pdf?42da4200dd38971a82c2d" | % { If ("$_" -match "(^.*)?\?"){ $matches[0].replace("?","") } else {""} }`